# Counting the amount of different qualitative values in multiple rows in R or Excel

Tags: r, excel

[screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dql1x.png)

Hi all,

I find it hard to explain my problem but here we go:

I have a dataset with the work experience of ~200 individuals. Each individual has as many rows as many positions they have worked in. What I essentially need to do, is somehow calculate is:

1. the amount of different firms the individual has worked (=the number of different company IDs per person),
2. the amount of different sectors the individual has worked in, and
3. whether the individual has prior CEO experience before a specific date (which I have data on).

I will then later perform a regression with e.g. amount of firms and sectors as countinuous variables and prior CEO experience as a dummy.

Do you have tips on how to do this effectively in either R or Excel? I hope the image I attached is visible.

Thank you!

//EDIT:

Here is a sample of my dataset:

```
> dput(head(Dataset)) 
structure(list(DirectorName = c("Alan Baldwin", "Alan Baldwin", 
"Alan Baldwin", "Alan Baldwin", "Alan Baldwin", "Alan Baldwin"
), CompanyName = c("Argosy International Inc", "Argosy International Inc", 
"CopperGlass Optical Solutions Inc", "INTEGRAL SYSTEMS INC (De-listed 07/2011)", 
"INTEGRAL SYSTEMS INC (De-listed 07/2011)", "INTEGRAL SYSTEMS INC (De-listed 07/2011)"
), BrdPosition = c("No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), RoleName = c("Consultant", 
"President/COO", "CEO", "Director - SD", "Independent Director", 
"Interim CEO"), DirectorID = c(510403, 510403, 510403, 510403, 
510403, 510403), CompanyID = c(1096955, 1096955, 733243, 16206, 
16206, 16206), DateStartRole = structure(c(1149120000, 1114905600, 
962409600, 1228867200, 1165363200, 1180483200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), DateEndRole = structure(c(1165363200, 1146441600, 
988675200, 1311724800, 1180483200, 1194912000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Sector = c(NA, NA, NA, "Software & Computer Services", 
"Software & Computer Services", "Software & Computer Services"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Please, could you share a sample of your dataset? Type on the console `dput(head(dataset))` and paste it in the question. I assume your dataset name is "dataset". This will help us to help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment! Is the sample in proper format? Additionally, I have data on the specific dates mentioned ("CEO experience before a specific date") on a seperate file as it is data from a seperate database. Do you have recommendations on how to refer to those dates, if that makes sense? I would happily share those here, but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` you can get there:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(DirectorID) %>%
    summarize( nCompanies = NROW(unique(CompanyID)),
               nSectors = NROW(unique(Sector)),
               CEOexperience = any(grepl("CEO", RoleName)))
```

This doesn't include the requirement of only CEO experience prior to a given date, which I think we need more info on before being able to incorporate this.

Comment: Thank you so much Pablo, this was very helpful! I'll try to add a sample from the dataset in a bit, if I can't manage that I'll try another way.